# Por que a veces funciona la animacion y otras no

Tags: java, animación

Hice dos programas de animaciones, muy parecidos, pero uno funcion y el otro no.
¿Cual podra ser la causa?
Pero al parece
les dejo el codigo de las dos animaciones:
animacion 1(mover en diagonal la palabra hola):

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{

     int x =0,y=100;

     Panel(){
         setLayout(null);
         setSize(1000,700);
         //setBackground(Color.BLUE);
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g);
         String mensaje= "hola";
         g.drawString(mensaje,x,y);
     }

     public void mover() {
         for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         x +=3;
         y +=3;
         repaint();
         try {
             Thread.sleep(100);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    
   }
}

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
        ventana.setBounds(0,0,1000,700);
        ventana.setLayout(null);
        Panel panel=new Panel();
        ventana.add(panel);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        panel.mover();
    }

}
```

Animacion 2 (desaparecer letras)[este no funciona]

```
 public class Texto extends JPanel{

    String texto = "Hola que tal"; 
    
    Texto(){
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(1000,700);
    }
    
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(new Font("serif",Font.BOLD,45));
        g.drawString(texto,100,100);
    }
    
    public void quitarLetras() {
        while(texto.length() > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            texto = texto.substring(0,texto.length()-1);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
    ventana.setBounds(0,0,1000,700);
    ventana.setLayout(null);
    Texto texto = new Texto();
    ventana.add(texto);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    texto.quitarLetras();
    
    
  }
}
```

de antemano gracias

Comment: te falta agregar [super.paint(g);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434158/what-is-use-of-super-paintg)  en el método `paint` de tu animacion 2

Comment: @dramaturgo efectivamente ese era el problema, gracias

Comment: @dramaturgo pone la respuesta abajo, para darte el puntaje